# How to get the bias-adjusted variance estimates for high-dimensional fixed effects in a linear model?

Tags: regression, linear-model, linear, fixed-effects-model, high-dimensional

I want to do a linear regression: $y_{i}=\psi_{j(i)}+X_{i}^{\prime} \xi+\varepsilon_{i}$, where $\psi_{j(i)}$ is a high dimensional fixed effect on group $j$, $X_i$ are the covariables of each observation $i$, and $\varepsilon_{i}$ is error assumed to be exogenous.

This linear regression can be done by many statistic packages through LSMR method avoids inverting the regressor matrix.

However after this regression I want to calculate the size weighted variance of the fixed effects $$\theta_{\psi}=\sum_{j=1}^{J} s_{j}\left(\psi_{j}-\bar{\psi}\right)^{2}$$, where $s_j$ is the share of the group. However the simple "plug-in" estimates $$\begin{aligned}
\hat{\theta}_{\psi} =\sum_{j=1}^{J} s_{j}\left(\hat{\psi}_{j}-\hat{\bar{\psi}}\right)^{2} =\sum_{j=1}^{J} s_{j}\left(\hat{\psi}_{j}\right)^{2}-(\hat{\bar{\psi}})^{2}
\end{aligned}$$ is upward biased because $$\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}\left[\hat{\theta}_{\psi}\right] &=\sum_{j=1}^{J} s_{j} \mathbb{E}\left[\left(\hat{\psi}_{j}\right)^{2}\right]-\mathbb{E}\left[(\hat{\psi})^{2}\right] \\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{J} s_{j}\left\{\psi_{j}^{2}+\mathbb{V}\left[\hat{\psi}_{j}\right]\right\}-(\bar{\psi})^{2}-\mathbb{V}[\hat{\bar{\psi}}] \\
&=\theta_{\psi}+\underbrace{\sum_{j=1}^{J} s_{j} \mathbb{V}\left[\hat{\psi}_{j}\right]-\mathbb{V}[\hat{\bar{\psi}}]}_{\text {bias }}
\end{aligned}$$.

A simple correction is to use the conventional HC standard error: $$\theta_{\psi} \approx \hat{\theta}_{\psi} - \sum_{j=1}^{J} s_{j} \hat{\mathbb{V}}_{H C}\left[\hat{\psi}_{j}\right]$$.

However the high dimensional effects estimated from LSMR method does not provide std errors. And thus I have no idea how to do this correction.

Another way to do correction is to assume  $\mathbb{V}[\varepsilon]=I \sigma^{2}$ and then direct calculate $$\mathbb{V}[\hat{\psi}]=\left(\tilde{F}^{\prime} \tilde{F}\right)^{-1} \sigma^{2}$$, where $\tilde{F}$ is residualized version of $F$, and $F$ is the dummy matrix of ${\psi}_{j(i)}$.

However I have no idea how to regress $F$ on $X$ to get the residual $\tilde{F}$ (how can I regress a dummy matrix on ?) and also how to inverse the $\left(\tilde{F}^{\prime} \tilde{F}\right)$.

Comment: How high dimensional is your dataset? 1000, 10k, 10M?

Comment: @eric_kernfeld It's about 100k in my case. But it can go up to 1m in the empirical literature I am study.

Comment: You can't get $\tilde F$ using LSMR?

Comment: What is the shape of the array $X$? 100k by something?

Comment: And what's the maximum value taken by $j$?

Comment: I am just asking because I don't want to propose something that won't scale adequately.

Comment: Thanks for you questions. The problem with $\tilde{F}$ is that to be honest I dont understand this part at all, I mean how can I regress a dummy matrix on $X$? And sorry I mistaken your first question. In my case, $i$ is about 5m, $j$ is about 100k, and $X$ has only 3-5 vectors.

Comment: One more question, and if the answer is "small" then an approximate solution might be easy. What's the maximum correlation between indicator vectors for your groups, and your covariates $X$?

Comment: Yes, actually I find some papers seem to use "Johnson-Lindenstrauss Approximation" to solve this computational problem, though I have no idea how to do it. I am not very clear about what do you mean by maximum correlation (should I calculate the correlation for each pair?). But if you are asking that if there will be some perfect collinearity between some vectors in $X$ and some vectors in $F$, I think the answer is no.

Comment: I was just wondering about how close your hat matrix is to being diagonal, which could simplify things.

Comment: Or rather, how close $([X|F]^T[X|F])^{-1}$ is to diagonal. (I edited this heavily for clarity).

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the answer to your question. Can you suggest some source from where I can learn to answer your answer?

Comment: I'm sorry, I've been unable to put in enough time to answer this properly, but I think the right ingredients are present so I will try to summarize. Two simplifications would help a lot. If the groups share no members, then the fixed effects and their standard errors can be estimated one at a time. If the covariates are not too correlated with any group, then you can either just forget about them, or replace Y with residuals from $Y = X \xi$ and then forget them. If either of these is not viable, then the sparse structure of the problem should still allow some way to get standard errors.

Comment: If the groups don't share members and the data within-group is iid, I think you could bootstrap the SEs by drawing within groups and re-estimating the coefficients. Is this practical to your situation?

Comment: @Matterhorn I don't think the bootstrap works because the bootstrap is trying to estimate the joint distribution of the outcome in regressors. When the regressors grow with the sample to 100 thousand or a million there will be the curse of dimensionality.